# How to download multiple files in Google Cloud Storage using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-workspace, gsutil

I am trying to download the exported data from my GSuite (Google Workplace) account. I want to download multiple selected files.

I tried running the following command:

```
gsutil -m cp \
  "gs://dummy-top-3bb5g8a2-s940-412a-bece-6f830889cc83/Status\ Red.pdf" \
  "gs://dummy-top-export-3bb5g8a2-s940-412a-bece-6f830889cc83/Status\ Report.jpg" \
  .
```

...but it failed with an error:

> CommandException: Wrong number of arguments for "cp" command.

How do I download my files?

Comment: I tested in my environment and this command worked for me.  I didn't escape my spaces in filenames since they were quoted.  Can you examine your script carefully and maybe post exactly how it is being run?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the backslashes are not successfully escaping the newline characters (maybe there's some other whitespace characters after the trailing backslashes?), thus the arguments on the subsequent lines are not being passed to the command.

Comment: is there a solution for this yet? It's pretty frustrating that the google cloud SDK shell won't successfully run the code provided by Google Cloud Storage for downloading multiple files.